# Spring Admin Console Not showing Eureka client with custom path

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am trying to register Spring boot Client with Spring boot Server. I added context-path in spring boot client. With out context-path it is successfully registering in server.

With custom context path it is successfully registering client but showing status as down and 404 not found.

Following are my application.properties:

```
server.contextPath: /api
spring.application.name: Order-Service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8180/eureka}
spring.boot.admin.url: http://localhost:1111
management.security.enabled: false
spring.boot.admin.username: admin
spring.boot.admin.password: admin123
server.port: 8081
```

While registering client i am getting following exceptions:

```
2017-09-17 14:50:58.707  INFO 15386 --- [    updateTask1] d.c.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdater    : Couldn't retrieve status for Application [id=0c833a5b, name=Customer-Service, managementUrl=http://192.168.254.14:8081, healthUrl=http://192.168.254.14:8081/health, serviceUrl=http://192.168.254.14:8081]

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://192.168.254.14:8081/health": Connect to 192.168.254.14:8081 [/192.168.254.14] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 192.168.254.14:8081 [/192.168.254.14] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:628)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:549)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.web.client.ApplicationOperations.doGet(ApplicationOperations.java:68)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.web.client.ApplicationOperations.getHealth(ApplicationOperations.java:58)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdater.queryStatus(StatusUpdater.java:111)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdater.updateStatus(StatusUpdater.java:65)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdater.updateStatusForAllApplications(StatusUpdater.java:58)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdateApplicationListener$2.run(StatusUpdateApplicationListener.java:60)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 192.168.254.14:8081 [/192.168.254.14] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2017-09-17 14:50:59.026 ERROR 15386 --- [    updateTask1] d.c.boot.admin.notify.SlackNotifier      : Couldn't notify for event de.codecentric.boot.admin.event.ClientApplicationStatusChangedEvent@12543e47 

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:628)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:423)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.notify.SlackNotifier.doNotify(SlackNotifier.java:58)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.notify.AbstractEventNotifier.notify(AbstractEventNotifier.java:39)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.notify.NotifierListener.onClientApplicationEvent(NotifierListener.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:253)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:350)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdater.updateStatus(StatusUpdater.java:78)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdater.updateStatusForAllApplications(StatusUpdater.java:58)
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdateApplicationListener$2.run(StatusUpdateApplicationListener.java:60)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```